# Amazon s3 bucket seems to be corrupting files

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using Amazon s3 and laravel 5 filesystems to upload files. The uploading of files works just fine but it seems like when the files have been uploaded to the bucket they are reducing in size and they cannot be read. For example in the screenshot below most files are being reduced to 24 bytes while some of them are as big as 2MB. I do not understand why this is happening and I need your help. Thanks.[image: My bucket contents]

Comment: Am not using `range`. I'm an AWS newbie and I do not know what range in AWS is..

Comment: This is the input  `<input  type="file" id="input-file-max-fs" name="announcement_file" class="dropify fs-anim-lower" data-max-file-size="2M" />` and this is how am uploading the file to s3 `$file = $filesystem->put($fileName, Request::file('announcement_file'), 'public');`

Comment: try this:  $filesystem->put($fileName, File::get((string)Request::file('announcement_file')), 'public'); I think right now if you check the content of the uploaded file you will see something like "tmp/asdasdasd.jpg" becase you just putting the filename in the content (dont forget to put "use File;" in the top)